# Excel match function on a table with many rows and columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I'm using this formula: ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data!$A:$A,{"Aaa","Bbb"},0))
but the fact is that I don't only want to mach "Aaa" and "Bbb" ; I have a full table of list codes in a table that has many rows and columns.

Do you know how to proceed so that the match function works on that kind of data?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: You need to check every single cell in column A? That's more than a million cells, so you're creating a lot of unnecessary calculation. You could use the `TOCOL` function on your table of codes in order to create a one-dimensional list which can be passed to `MATCH`.

Comment: Ok thank you. I don't need the entire A column, it is just for the example. But I have a problem, I can't use the TOCOL function since my excel version is too old I think.

Comment: Use `MAP()` with `COUNTIFS()`.

Comment: If you don't have `MAP`, as suggested by Harun24hr, use a simple `COUNTIF`, e.g. `=COUNTIF(F$2:G$11,Data!A2)` and copy this formula down. Change `F$2:G$11` as required.

Comment: Thank you a lot it works! And is there a way to avoid blank cell?

Comment: "the match function works .. "  --> https://exceljet.net/articles/index-and-match | pls share if it solves (or not) for ur situation..